# How can I use a SharpDX.Toolkit.Game in multiple WPF controls?

Tags: optimization, sharpdx, wpf

I've implemented a Game class in a WPF app. It works and the animation renders.

I have task to implement another several Controls with SharpDX in the same application window. Each new Game object takes a lot of memory (about 25MB each).

How can I save memory when creating over a dozen controls rendering different animations in SharpDX?

---

I thought about creating one Game object and share it between different controls.  However, each control contains another animation. Adding new control I tried two things:

- create new SharpDXElement for each control, then call Game.Switch(dxElement);
- create one SharpDXElement for each control

Both failed: Only one control displays. The rest are invisible.

I also tried quickly switching the `dxElement`, but that caused blinking.